# Split string into two variables after specific length

Tags: c#

I need to split a string into two string variables at a specific length, more exactly after the first two characters.

Example 1: `XX123456789` should be split into:

- val1: `XX`
- val2: `123456789`

Example 2: string `NN125457878` should be split into:

- val1: `NN`
- val2: `125457878`

Comment: I tought to use string.Substring(0,2) ... but this will work for the first part because the second part can have different length ... or maybe ... string.Substring(2, string.Length)?

Comment: It is just SubString(2) for the second part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`String.Substring(Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.Substring(Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads like;

```
string s = "XX123456789";
string val1 = s.Substring(0, 2);
string val2 = s.Substring(2);
Console.WriteLine(val1);
Console.WriteLine(val2);
```

Prints;

```
XX
123456789
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/y9EWrG)</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the Substring method.

For the first one, you would specify the start index of `0`, with a length of `2`. For the second one, you would use a start index of `2` and no length, which will return everything in the string from the third character until the end.

See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx).

```
var theString = "XX123456789";
var val1 = theString.Substring(0, 2);
var val2 = theString.Substring(2);
```